# How to call a void C# web method with jQuery AJAX?

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, webmethod

Can someone teach me how I can call this example C# web method with AJAX and jQuery?

```
public class Default {
        [WebMethod]
        public static void Example()
        {
            //do something
        } }
```

Comment: `WebMethod` is [no longer supported](http://johnwsaunders3.wordpress.com/2011/12/07/more-reasons-to-not-use-asmx-services-in-new-code/) by Microsoft. You might wish to look into the replacement technology for REST based services, [ASP.NET Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api). It has a cleaner model and is supported by Microsoft.

Answer (score 4):

I've had no problem using the below method:

**Javascript**

```
var dataParam='{"param":"1"}'; //or whatever data you may be sending or not sending

$.ajax({
   type : "POST",
   url : myHomeUrl + '/SendDataVoid',
   contentType : "application/json; charset=utf-8",
   data : dataParam,
   datatype : "json",
}).done(function (data) {
    alert('success');
}).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
   alert(jqXHR.getResponseHeader("error"));
});
```

**C#**

```
[WebMethod]
public static void SendDataVoid(string param)
{
    try
    {
       //do stuff here
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        System.Web.Services.WebService wsError = new System.Web.Services.WebService();
        wsError.Context.Response.StatusCode = 500;

        wsError.Context.Response.AppendHeader("error", ex.Message);

    }
}
```

That enables you to be able to send an actual error msg back instead of a generic "Internal Server" error.

Comment: So what, "data" is being returned?